# Can we rewrite relative adverbs in this manner?

Tags: relative-adverbs

I was studying relative adverb, One example was given

> I will never forget the day when I first met Susie.

I am just curious. Can we write it like this

> The day, When I first met Susie is unforgettable

Is it grammatically  correct?

Comment: ...and capitalization.

Comment: @Davo Sorry I am not very good in typing, I updated my question, Please let me know if there is still any mistake

Comment: No, you must write it like this : _The day when I first met Susie is unforgettable_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I will never forget the day when I first met Susie.
>
> The day when I first met Susie is unforgettable.

Gramatically, both sentences are correct. *(A couple corrected mistakes in the 2nd sent.)*

But, the meaning is a little different in the second sentence. Notice how, in the first, you convey how **you** will never forget the day you met Susie. But, in the second sentence, you're making a statement, that *the day, when I [you] first met Susie, is unforgettable.* Here exists a slight implication that the day is unforgettable *for everyone,* which is false (speaking out of context). Also, this sentence is less personal than the first one, as it says *unforgettable.*

Nevertheless, generally both sentences are **gramatically correct, and have more or less the same meaning. Also, the usage of the relative adverb *when* is correct.**

Comment: But the second example is not passive.

Comment: Indeed, it's not, this was a mistake. Either way answer still clarifies it.

Comment: @Andrew - Still, you should fix the mistake.